# почему git отказывается пушить коммиты?

Tags: git

работал изначально только со своим репозиторием, но теперь появилась необходимость работать и со сторонным репозиторием - прописал локально следующие команды:

```
git config --local user.name "somebody10000"
git config --local user.email airewright.ru@gmail.com
git branch -M main
```

при выполнении команды `git push -u airewright.ru main` - получаю следующий вывод:

```
remote: Permission to somebody10000/airewright.ru.git denied to ReijiAkkerman.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/somebody10000/airewright.ru.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

при этом команды `git add .` и `git commit -m "1"` - были выполнены успешно

вот то что выдает команда `git config -l --show-scope`:

```
global  user.name=ReijiAkkerman
global  user.email=reijiakkerman@gmail.com
global  safe.directory=/var/www/haruproject.space
global  safe.directory=/var/www/html
local   core.repositoryformatversion=0
local   core.filemode=true
local   core.bare=false
local   core.logallrefupdates=true
local   remote.airewright.ru.url=https://github.com/somebody10000/airewright.ru.git
local   remote.airewright.ru.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/airewright.ru/*
local   user.name=somebody10000
local   user.email=airewright.ru@gmail.com
```

Не понимаю что я сломал, в прошлый раз коммиты пушились без проблем. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: То, что gît add и gît commit успешно выполнились не говорит вообще ни о чем, кроме  того, что локальный репозиторий существует и в порядке.

Comment: @Эникейщик я не понимаю почему git при пуше ссылается на пользователя указанного в глобальных настройках а не локальных, в доках написано что локальные настройки имеют наивысший приоритет перед всеми остальными

Comment: Проверяйте права на репозиторий. Вам отказано в доступе на пуши коммитов. + как правило, пушить в мастер ветку запрещено. Попробуйте запушить в другую ветку(создать новую)

Comment: Вы напутали настройки имени пользователя для коммитов (user.name) и настройки доступа.

Comment: @SwaD проблема как раз таки в том что (как я понял) git пытается получить доступ к репозиториям пользователя `ReijiAkkerman` а должен по идее подключаться к `somebody10000`

Comment: @user7860670 можете по подробнее рассказать о настройках доступа? или ссылку кинуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.name` в git и аккаунт на Github это разные вещи.
То какой стоит `user.name` отвечает лишь за то, какое имя будет отображаться в описании коммита.

Первое сообщение (`remote: ...`) говорит, что git (скорее всего, с помощью встроенного Credential Manager'а) попытался обратиться к Github (remote) с аккаунта `ReijiAkkerman`.

Способы аутентификации на Github: https://docs.github.com/ru/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line

Comment: как мне поменять аккаунт с которого git-у нужно обращаться? это можно где-то прописать?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman ответ на этот вопрос зависит от того каким образом ты авторизуешься на Github.

Comment: я использую https, и так же когда это требуется ввожу access-токен в поле где с меня он просит пароль, так это и работало до сегодняшнего дня - теперь он даже не спрашивает с какого аккаунта мне зайти а сразу выбивает ошибку

Comment: может где-то прописывается пользователь по умолчанию - если да то как его удалить чтобы он как и раньше спрашивал с какого аккаунта войти?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman Если ты подключается по HTTPS значит используешь Git Credential Manager, как его настроить на работу с несколькими аккаунтами Github вопрос хороший. Ещё есть вариант перейти на аутентификацию по SSH. Вот гайд по настройке: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274407/14633731

Comment: ошибка была именно в том что я использовал терминал VSCode где у меня уже привязан аккаунт - с терминала Ubuntu  все работатет отлично)) - Спасибо))))